# No Headphone sound

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones

I recently bought an HP 6720s and switched out the Vista HDD for my Ubuntu system. Everything works fine, including the sound. But when I plug in the headphones it's dead. I also noticed the mic isn't recording anything, even though it's active.

`lspci -v` says:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30d8
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at e4624000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

I was wondering if someone could help me troubleshoot this? Thanks in advance...

Comment: can you copy the result of this command `aplay -l`

Comment: Sure. It's **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD1981 Analog [AD1981 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Answer (score 1):

The following advice given by Big Show worked very well. Although my internal mic doesn't work, the mic on my webcam does and that's good enough for me right now. After making the following changes, I also installed Pulse Audio Manager and had to unmute the mic. Thanks 'Big Show'!

Open the terminal and type this command:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Now insert this line at end of this file which is opened:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=hp-dv5 enable_msi=1
```

After inserting this line just save the file (CTRL + S & CTRL = Q) and the reboot with:

`sudo reboot` (Or just restart the normal way you do.)

Double check your settings after the reboot by opening alsamixer at the Terminal and check volume labels in alsamixer. Particularly make sure "Auto-Mute" is set to "Disabled".

(To open alsamixer just type `alsamixer` in terminal.)

Also, make sure your mic isn't muted in the sound preferences applet.

Comment: Who's 'Big Show'?

Answer (score 0):

First, see if  you have any standby problem (test after complete shutdown, and also test after  standby)

Then, you may (or not) solve this problem by tweaking the alsa-base.conf file:
In a terminal, run this:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

In the editor window , insert this line at the end

```
options snd-hda-intel model=hp
```

Save file and reboot.

If that doesn't work, you can again edit `alsa-base.conf` and
try replacing `hp` with `basic`

source: [HDA intel Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto)
For info, the possible model option for your AD1981 codec is obtained looking the corresponding block in this command's output:

```
zcat /usr/share/doc/alsa-base/driver/HD-Audio-Models.txt.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type this command

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
```

(This command will open a file)
Now insert this line at end of this file:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=hp-dv5 enable_msi=1
```

After inserting this line just save that file.

Now Reboot and you are good to go.
To check after this, open `alsamixer` through Terminal and check volume labels in alsamixer (to open alsamixer just type `alsamixer` in terminal).